# updateMinChanges in Couchbase is not working

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I want my Couchbase bucket to do indexing only after x (lets say 2) PUTs.
So I set in viewUpdateDaemon the parameters to be as follows:

```
{
    "updateInterval": 5000,
    "updateMinChanges": 2,
    "replicaUpdateMinChanges": 0
}
```

and in my code when I'm querying the view I run:

```
result = bucket.query(ViewQuery.from(viewDesignServices, viewService_emails).keys(emailArray).stale(Stale.FALSE));
```

However now when I'm querying my view via the web UI it doesn't return the newly added docs at all.

Any help will be good,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Are you views Development Views or Production Views?

The indexer doesn't run automatically on Development Views, so that could explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the request is form data.

So you should post it as such.

Content could be (for your case):

updateInterval=5000&updateMinChanges=2&replicaUpdateMinChanges=0